# Display PHP info in a table based layout

Tags: php, html, wordpress, html-table

I am trying to display a 'meet the team' page in a 2x5 table, working with code written by the previous web designer in Wordpress.

This is the page I am looking at - http://www.stirling-house.com/about-us/meet-the-team As I say, I want to display the pictures in a table, so it looks neater.

The code I have is -

```
<div id="maintext">
    <h1>MEET THE TEAM</h1>
    <h3>THE STIRLING HOUSE ADMINISTRATION TEAM</h3>
    <?php $members =get_posts('numberposts=99&cat=4&order=ASC'); //print_r($members); 
    foreach ($members as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post);?> 
    <div class="member-box">
        <img src="<?php echo get('member_photo');?>" alt="" style="margin:5px 7px 0 0;" />
        <h3><?php echo $post->post_title;?></h3>
        <h4><?php echo get('member_designation');?></h4>
```

Can anyone help?!

Comment: How much work have you done with CSS before? I would try changing the `display` property for `member-box` to **inline-block** and see if that gets you closer to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is by adding a counter before the foreach (for example, `$n`), initialize it to zero and increment it every time the loop finishes. Then, make all the odd divs float to the left and the even ones float to the right.

This is how the code would look like (more or less):

```
<? 
$n = 0; // Counter
foreach($members as $post){
    if($n % 2) $style="float:left";
    else $style="float:right";

    <img src="<?php echo get('member_photo');?>" alt="" style="margin:5px 7px 0 0;" />
    <h3><?php echo $post->post_title;?></h3>
    <h4><?php echo get('member_designation');?></h4>
```

If that does not work, you can try using a `table` layout and placing a `<tr>` tag after $n rows (resetting the counter every time you add a `<tr>`).

Answer (score 0):

It is the opinion of most web designers (post-2005 or so) that `<table>` elements should not be used for layout/design. If you add the following CSS rule to your sites, stylesheet:

```
.member-box { display: inline-block; }
```

You will get something that looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkeL3.jpg

Sorry to answer indirectly, but I think this is the answer you're *really* looking for... ;)

Comment: Wow, thank you for the super quick responses!

The CSS worked a treat :)

Comment: No problem. If this has worked for you then please mark this as the **answer** by clicking the tick on the left :)